# Attaching text label and/or icon to div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a div to hold several status messages and/or icons, I'm using dhtmlx, however it should be applicable to general javascript/html/css. StatusBar is the bottom line on the browser.

```
moUI.statusMain = moUI.layoutMain.attachStatusBar();     // Status bar initialization\setup
moUI.statusMain.id = "statusMain";
moUI.statusMain.setText("<div id=\"toolbarObj\"></div><div style=\"\"><textarea rows=\"1\" cols=\"20\" id=\"status_txt\" type=\"text\" value=\"Initializing.\"><textarea rows=\"1\" cols=\"20\" id=\"operation_txt\" type=\"text\" value=\"COPY\"></div>");
```

I can then modify the text like this

```
document.getElementById("status_txt").value = "Done.";
```

Problem with textarea is that the second area never shows up, they have a scrollbar and if user clicks in the box the browser crashes. if I use input, I get both texts, however I am not really looking for any input, and pure text does not allow me to pinpoint the text I want to modify. Also how do I insert an icon?

Comment: Did you know you are supposed to close your textareas with a `</textarea>` tag? Or that they don't take a `value` attribute?

Comment: thanks, realized that a second after I hit submit

Comment: I guess what I am looking for is another type of control rather than textarea or input, just a plain text label and/or icon, that I can reference later and modify.

Comment: Just use a `<span>` and extract the text content of that element instead using `.textContent`.

Comment: Thanks, it works :) Though it brought up a new problem, how do I place the text at fixed positions?

Comment: A new problem should be posted as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Blazemonger I got a solution that works for me. Below is the code that will place text and icons at absolute positions across a line, allowing me to switch out text(s) and icon(s) at any given time.

```
moUI.statusMain.setText("<style type=\"text/css\">  </style><div id=\"toolbarObj\"></div><div><span id=\"status_txt\" style=\"max-width: 400px; position:absolute;left:0;top:0\"> Initializing.</span> <img id=\"status_img\" src=\"" + URL_TOOLBAR_IMAGES + "database.png\" alt=\"\" style=\"max-width: 400px; position:absolute;left:100px;top:0\"/></span><span id=\"operation_txt\" style=\"max-width: 400px; position:absolute;left:200px;top:0;\">COPY</span></div>");
document.getElementById("status_txt").textContent = "Done.";
document.getElementById("operation_txt").textContent = "COPY";
```